Ошибка при запуске приложения на android
Вылетает такая ошибка:

Process: com.example.recview2, PID: 10144
android.view.InflateException:
Binary XML file line #23 in com.example.recview2:layout/list_item: Binary XML file line #23 in com.example.recview2:layout/list_item: Error inflating class TextView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException:
Binary XML file line #23 in com.example.recview2:layout/list_item: Error inflating class TextView
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
Can't convert value at index 93 to dimension: type=0x12, theme={InheritanceMap=[id=0x7f100275com.example.recview2:style/Theme.RecView2, id=0x7f100078com.example.recview2:style/Base.Theme.RecView2, id=0x7f100236com.example.recview2:style/Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar, id=0x7f100244com.example.recview2:style/Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar, id=0x7f10023ecom.example.recview2:style/Theme.Material3.Light, id=0x7f10005fcom.example.recview2:style/Base.Theme.Material3.Light, id=0x7f1000b4com.example.recview2:style/Base.V24.Theme.Material3.Light, id=0x7f10008ecom.example.recview2:style/Base.V14.Theme.Material3.Light, id=0x7f100263com.example.recview2:style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light, id=0x7f10006ecom.example.recview2:style/Base.Theme.MaterialComponents.Light, id=0x7f1000a8com.example.recview2:style/Base.V21.Theme.MaterialComponents.Light, id=0x7f100096com.example.recview2:style/Base.V14.Theme.MaterialComponents.Light, id=0x7f100097com.example.recview2:style/Base.V14.Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge, id=0x7f10013bcom.example.recview2:style/Platform.MaterialComponents.Light, id=0x7f10021acom.example.recview2:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light, id=0x7f100052com.example.recview2:style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light, id=0x7f1000bacom.example.recview2:style/Base.V28.Theme.AppCompat.Light, id=0x7f1000b7com.example.recview2:style/Base.V26.Theme.AppCompat.Light, id=0x7f1000b1com.example.recview2:style/Base.V23.Theme.AppCompat.Light, id=0x7f1000afcom.example.recview2:style/Base.V22.Theme.AppCompat.Light, id=0x7f1000a4com.example.recview2:style/Base.V21.Theme.AppCompat.Light, id=0x7f1000bdcom.example.recview2:style/Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light, id=0x7f100138com.example.recview2:style/Platform.AppCompat.Light, id=0x7f100143com.example.recview2:style/Platform.V25.AppCompat.Light, id=0x1030241android:style/Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar, id=0x1030237android:style/Theme.Material.Light, id=0x103000candroid:style/Theme.Light, id=0x1030005android:style/Theme], Themes=[com.example.recview2:style/Theme.RecView2, forced, com.example.recview2:style/Theme.AppCompat.Empty, forced, android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.DarkActionBar, forced]}
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:795)

При этом в коде ошибок не вижу.
Код активити activity_main с RecyclerView:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recView">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Код элемента (Айтема) list_item.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Ivan Ivanov"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/fullname_txt"
></TextView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="8class"
        android:lastBaselineToBottomHeight="@+id/fullname_txt"
android:layout_below="@id/fullname_txt"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/clas_txt">

    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/fullname_txt"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="27sp"
        android:id="@+id/skills_txt"
        >
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>

Код адаптера:
package com.example.recview2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

public class StudentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StudentAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Student> students;

    StudentAdapter(Context context, List<Student> students) {
        this.students = students;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull StudentAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
Student student = students.get(position);
holder.fullName.setText(student.getFullname());
        holder.clas.setText(Integer.toString(student.getclas()));
        holder.skills.setText(Integer.toString(student.getskills()));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return students.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            TextView clas, fullName, skills;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View view) {
            super(view);
            fullName = view.findViewById(R.id.fullname_txt);
            clas = view.findViewById(R.id.clas_txt);
            skills = view.findViewById(R.id.skills_txt);

        }
    }
}

Код MainActivity.java:
package com.example.recview2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private RecyclerView recView;
private ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recView = findViewById(R.id.recView);

        inizilazieData();


        StudentAdapter studentAdapter = new StudentAdapter(this, students);
        recView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recView.setAdapter(studentAdapter);

    }

    public  void inizilazieData() {

        students.add(new Student("Iban Ivanov", 1, 2));
        students.add(new Student("Petro Ivanov", 1, 2));
        students.add(new Student("Vannn Ivanov", 1, 2));
        students.add(new Student("bb Ivanov", 1, 2));



    }
}

При этом все проверил, ошибок нигде нет, но приложение не запускается и вылетает.
В чем может быть дело?

блоки кода с просмотром предназначены для кода на Javascript + HTML + CSS, так как такой код может быть выполнен в браузере., а не для кода на основных языках программирования типа Java/Python или конфигурации типа XML.

это работает в видеоуроке по которому я делал этот код. ЧТо мне исправит?

Сравните что написано в документации атрибута android:lastBaselineToBottomHeight и что прописано у вас: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:lastBaselineToBottomHeight

Нужно изменить атрибут android:lastBaselineToBottomHeight. Ему нужно назначить некоторую величину, равную расстоянию от базовой линии последней строки до нижнего края RelativeLayout, а не идентификатор вышестоящего элемента.
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="8class"
    android:lastBaselineToBottomHeight="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/fullname_txt"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/clas_txt">

